# Did anyone succeed in using Truffle with Node v6?

Tags: truffle, nodejs, bug

Truffle looks to be buggy when using with Node v6 (installed from homebrew). There's a [ticket](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle/issues/147) on Truffle github, but none seems to take it into account. Are people not using Node v6 or is there a workaround I didn't notice ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an [issue of Pudding](https://github.com/ConsenSys/ether-pudding/pull/25) that is fixed and will be merged soon.